# Scanf doesn't wait for input

Tags: c

I have a problem. When I run this it just spams "Bigger" instead of letting me write to scanf. Could someone try to explain why and what I could do to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int rn, n=0;
    rn=rand();
    while (n!=rn){
        scanf("%n", &n);
        if (n<rn)
            printf("\nBigger\n");
        else if (n>rn)
            printf("\nSmaller\n");
    }
    printf("\nCorrect\n");
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%n", &n);` --> `scanf("%d", &n);`

Comment: `scanf("%d", &n);` => `if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%n` is incorrect. You probably want `%d` and you should check what `scanf()` returns to check for error.

From `man scanf`:

> ```
>  n     Nothing is expected; instead, the number of characters consumed
>        thus far from the input is stored through the next pointer, which
>        must be a pointer to int.  This is not a conversion, although it
>        can be suppressed with the * flag.
> ```